# How do I do a keybind involving <C-ñ>?

Tags: vimrc, command

I use a keyboard layout designed for Spanish speakers and I've remapped hjkl to jklñ because those are the main home row keys. With hjkl I have to be constantly moving my hand to the left in order to move around in my file.

So what I want is to setup a command that uses <C-ñ>, but when I tried doing that, it just didn't work. It didn't do anything. Does anyone know what I could do?

Comment: Mapping `Ctrl-x` where x is not in a-z is nerver gurantee to work in Vim.  I fear it will not work.

Comment: you might be interested in the langmap or keymap options (also `:help language-mapping`, `:help mbyte-keymap`)

Comment: One interesting experiment to do is to verify what are the codes sent to Vim when the `Ctrl-ñ` is sent. You can do that by typing in insert mode:  `Ctrl-v Ctrl-ñ`. With that input you can map this sequence of code to the sequence you like (sometime it works ;-) )

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that info! The answer was sadly disappointing though, it just doesn't send any code to vim at all